# Bootstrap - Aligning two rows accordingly / padding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i want to create a responsive webpage with twitter bootstrap. I have a picture which should be a certain width and a bar with a background color which should have the same width and both should be aligned on the left and right side.

As Bootstrap uses `padding-left:-15px; padding-right:-15px;` I have this effect:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/thsgC

This confuses me. How can I align both rows with Bootstrap accordingly without overwriting bootstraps own css classes `.row` and `.col-xs-12`

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Bootstrap the `col-*` class has padding on it. To get around it you can either override it (not recommended) or place the background coloured div inside another div:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="navigation">color</div>
</div>
```

Like this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ixcmg

Answer (score 1):

Actually both rows are aligned correctly. The problem is in the first row, image element is child of `col-xs-12` element while in second row, `navigation` class is on the same div element which has `col-xs-12` element

try to put `navigation` class in child element of `col-xs-12` like this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class = "navigation">
            color
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

also its not good practice to overwrite bootstrap's own classes, you can give extra class to the element which should be used to overwrite bootstrap css property values.